# How to track URL source?

Tags: url, google-analytics, tracking

I have in my website "See More" link, what do I need to add to the link in order to see or count how many people using the "See More" link (with google analytics). This link is custom and unique per post. Is there any UTM parameter that I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event tracker to track when the link is clicked.

```
<a href='seemore.html' onclick="ga ('send', 'event', 'See more', 'click', this.href);">
```

This captures the link click as an event with the fully qualified url as the label. You can then see these events in the Events reports.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

If the see more target is another page, you can use enhanced link attribution: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en.